# Shiny not responsive to multiple tabsetpanels

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to include multiple `tabsetPanel` in the `mainPanel` of a Shiny app. When I launch the app, it's not showing anything as if the app is trying to figure out the UI element without getting into the server elements at all.

Anyone knows why this is the case?

Below is a minimal example based on the Shiny app template in RStudio.

*ui.R*

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       sliderInput("bins",
                   "Number of bins:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 50,
                   value = 30)
    ),

    # Multiple tabset panels
    mainPanel(
      h2("tabsetpanel1"),
      tabsetPanel(id = "pan1",
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("tab1", plotOutput("distPlot"))),
      h2("tabsetpanel2"),
      tabsetPanel(id = "pan2",
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("tab2", plotOutput("distPlot")))
    )
  )
))
```

*server.R*

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outputs have to be unique you cant have multiple `"distPlot"`, Change to something like this:

```
data <- reactive({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})

  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    data()
  })

  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    data()
  })
```

Then in your `ui`

```
plotOutput("distPlot1")

plotOutput("distPlot2")
```